# Defining a command that adds a letter to another command

Tags: macros, renewcommand

Suppose I have defined two commands, e.g.

`\newcommand{\commandA}{\alpha}`

`\newcommand{\commandAB}{\alpha^2}`

I would like to define a command that makes `\commandA` into `\commandAB` by simply adding the letter B to this command, so that the output is

`\endswithB{\commandA}=\commandAB`

My naive try to define

`\endswithB{\desiredcommand}[1]{#1B}`

only produces `\endswithB{\commandA}={\commandA}B`.

To give context, I have a set of around thirty commands for certain mathematical symbols. These are all of the form `\commandA`.
I have a related set of commands for a related set of symbols, such that all these commands are exactly as the previous commands but with the extra letter B in the end, i.e. `\commandAB` (but they produce quite different symbols).
There are currently situations where I am unsure which symbol I actually want to use, so I would prefer if I could just work for now with a command for these situations

`\newcommand{\unsure}[1]{#1}`

that I later on could simply change to

`\newcommand{\unsure}[1]{\endswithB{#1}}`

if I decide that that's better.

Comment: Hi, please give an example of what You want to achieve

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh I tried giving some more context.

Comment: It appears that \newcommand does not like any command starting with \end (probably reserved for environments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but it works without errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\withB}[1]{\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1B\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\fooA}{A}
\newcommand{\fooAB}{B}

\begin{document}
\withB{\fooA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't give errors, but it gives aso no output `:-)`. You probably want `\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1B\endcsname`.

Comment: Eek!  It was showing me an older version of the PDF.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\commandA}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\commandAB}{\alpha^2}

%\newcommand{\unsure}[1]{#1}% this is easy
\newcommand{\unsure}[1]{\EndsWithB{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\EndsWithB}{m}
 {
  \use:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 B }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\commandA$

$\commandAB$

$\unsure{\commandA}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\use:c` you tell LaTeX to form a command name from its argument, which is the argument to `\EndsWithB` deprived of the backslash and with a `B` appended to it.